# cancelPreviousPerformRequests does not seem to work in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

As the title states, for some reason, the following (simplified) code is not working:

```
extension InputView: {

    func updateTable(text: String) {
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(loadPlaces(text:)), object: nil)
          //NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)

            self.perform(#selector(loadPlaces(text:)), with: text, afterDelay: 0.5)

            prevSearch = inputField.text!;
        }

    //Private wrapper function
    @objc private func loadPlaces(text: String) {
        print("loading results for: \(text)")
       // locator?.searchTextHasChanged(text: text)
    }
}
```

I call `updateTable` every time a user edits a `UITextField`, which calls `localPlaces` which calls a function that queries google's online places API (commented out). Unfortunately, the print line in loadPlaces is called after every single call to updateTable. From my visual inspection, it seems there is in fact a delay to the print statements, however, the old calls do not cancel. I've tried looking on a lot of StackOverflow threads but I couldn't find anything updated for Swift 3. Am I calling something incorrectly?

*PS.* If I instead use the commented out, single-argument, `cancelPreviousPerformRequests`. It works for some reason.

---

**Edit:** I have been able to replicate this error in a separate project. So I'm 100% sure that the above code is wrong. If you would like to replicate this error, open up a new iOS project and paste the following code into the default `ViewController`:

```
class InputView: UIView {

    func updateTable(text: String) {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(loadPlaces(text:)), object: nil)

        self.perform(#selector(loadPlaces(text:)), with: text, afterDelay: 0.5)

    }

    //Private wrapper function
    @objc private func loadPlaces(text: String) {
        print("loading results for: \(text)")
        // locator?.searchTextHasChanged(text: text)
    }
}




class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let input = InputView()

        for i in 0..<200 {
            input.updateTable(text: "Call \(i)")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The explanation in Duncan C's answer is not appropriate for this case.

In the reference of [`cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget:selector:object:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1410849-cancelpreviousperformrequests):

> ### Discussion
>
> All perform requests are canceled that have the same target as `aTarget`, argument as `anArgument`, and selector as
> `aSelector`.

So, when you have a line like:

```
<aTarget>.perform(<aSelector>, with: <anArgument>, afterDelay: someDelay)
```

You can cancel it with:

```
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: <aTarget>, selector: <aSelector>, object: <anArgument>)
```

only when all 3 things `aTarget`, `aSelector` **and `anArgument`** match.

---

Please try something like this and check what you see:

```
class InputView: UIView {
    
    var lastPerformArgument: NSString? = nil
    
    func updateTable(text: String) {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(loadPlaces(text:)), object: lastPerformArgument)

        lastPerformArgument = text as NSString
        self.perform(#selector(loadPlaces(text:)), with: lastPerformArgument, afterDelay: 0.5)
        
    }
    
    //Private wrapper function
    @objc private func loadPlaces(text: String) {
        print("loading results for: \(text)")
        // locator?.searchTextHasChanged(text: text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I was under the impression that passing nil for the `object` parameter would serve as a wildcard, like the way the notification manager allows you to either specify a particular object or pass nil to ignore that parameter. Apparently not. If you pass nil in the cancel request then the object must have been invoked with a nil argument. Good catch, and thanks for correcting me. (Voted)

Comment: @DuncanC, I understand. This sort of inconsistency often confuses us developers. Maybe we should say more to Apple.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: @OOPer why do you cast it to NSString since String also works just fine?

Comment: @gafos, sorry, frankly I do not remember why. Maybe confused with equality and identity, I believe String worked even in Swift 3,  but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

The first part of this answer is wrong. See the edit at the bottom for updated information. I'm leaving the original answer since the discussion might be useful.

It looks to me like there is a bug in the way `NSObject` maps Swift function names to selectors that is preventing this from working correctly. The only way I was able to get the `cancelPreviousPerformRequests` function to actually cancel the pending `perform()` is if the function does not have any parameters. If the function takes a single anonymous parameter or a named parameter then the `cancelPreviousPerformRequests` function does not cancel the pending `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`.

Another bug I've found: If you use a function with an anonymous parameter, e.g.:

```
func foo(_ value: String) {
  print("In function \(#function)")
}
```

Then the result you see in the print statement is:

```
In function foo
```

You'll see the same thing if the function has 2, 3, or more anonymous parameters.

If you have a function with **no** parameters, you get a different result:

```
func foo() {
  print("In function \(#function)")
}
```

That code will display the message:

```
In function foo()
```

(Note the parentheses after the function name.)

## EDIT

Note that it seems I was wrong. Apparently the `object` parameter to `cancelPreviousPerformRequests` must match what was passed in. You can only pass `object:nil` to `cancelPreviousPerformRequests` if the selector was invoked with a nil argument.

To quote the docs:

> The argument for requests previously registered with the
> perform(*:with:afterDelay:) instance method. Argument equality is
> determined using isEqual(*:), so the value need not be the same object
> that was passed originally. Pass nil to match a request for nil that
> was originally passed as the argument.

Comment: Check out OOPer's answer.